# Activating a differnt workbook, subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

Im getting pretty frustrated here. the ling `workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Activate` is giving me a `Subscript out of range` error in the following code

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim i As Long, j As Integer, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, mntname As String
i = 1
lastrow1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'
Do While i < lastrow1
j = month(Range("A" & i))
mntname = monthname(j)
Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Activate
Sheets(mntname).Range("A" & Rows.Count + 1).PasteSpecial
Workbooks("Book2.xls").Activate
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

`Book2 is` is open and ready to be used. A are the sheets. 
`mntname` when highlighted is converting properly to a sting value which is one of the sheets in Book2

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it??

Comment: So you have two workbooks open called Book2 but with different extensions?

Comment: Sorry about that I have book1 and book2 (Creative Names) and i gett the error going from book1 to book2

Comment: The one that I am copying from is macro enabled. However checking the properties of book2 and it is .xlsx Ijust tried changing the name of it and the code, no luck

Comment: For some everso unknown reason, when I was forced toreset my computer (software update, unrealted) it worked perfectly afterwards, well done good sir. If you post your code again, i can garentee you the points

Answer (score 2):

It is just

```
Workbooks("Book2").Activate.
```

The name of the workbook is only `Book2`, `Book2.xls` is the name of the file.